# Deploying a Profile with Enabled Apex Class Access & Visualforce Page Access

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, profile, migration

I need to deploy a profile from dev to staging org, and I was looking for any possible ways to include Apex Class Access & Visualforce Page Access to the ant's changeset (I would like to avoid manual post-deploy steps).

If not with ant tool, can it be done programmatically at all, using metadata api? It wouldn't be a problem for me to write a simple script to do so, I just need to know whether this is feasible.

This is dev org:
[image]
This is staging org:
[image]

Comment: It will only deploy access for *included* components. You must include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all the classes
,pages,objects and Fields for which you need access in package.xml along with all the profiles. Then u can retrieve the permissions from dev and able to deploy in stage.